# App not getting data from Graph API anymore & problems filling out for review

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

Take a breath... it's a very specific question, not directly a bug.
(But I can't get an answer from Facebook, after thousands of FAQ pages I somehow landed in a chat with Facebook Advertisers Support, they told me to come here.)

## Description of my app

I have a Facebook Page, on which I'm sharing events from some other Facebook Pages I'm cooperating with. Kind of an event aggregator. The main goal is to help people who are new in town to find all that interesting events and the groups and pages they are organized by.

As you can imagine, it's based on a server-side application, that collects the upcoming events through Graph API and posts on my own Facebook Page the day before the event.

Of course I had to give the server-side application the `manage_pages` and `publish_pages` right. This Facebook App will never be used by an end-user, I'm the only user and I'm only posting to my own Facebook Page.

The server-side application worked fine for more than a year.
I just started a Facebook Ad Campaign and poster and flyers are currently being printed. And now...

## What broke

You all heard of Cambridge Analytica. Due to these bad guys Facebook is currently changing a lot. One change was this:

> As we begin enhancing our new app review process and make changes to our platform, the Events, Groups, Pages and Instagram APIs will no longer be available to new developers. Testing of our more robust process starts today and the new process should resume in a few weeks, but **apps currently accessing Events and Groups APIs will lose access today**. Going forward, **access to these APIs will require a formal app review** and for apps using the Pages API, submission is required within 90 days once app review resumes or access will be removed.

(See https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/04/04/facebook-api-platform-product-changes)

Since nearly two weeks my server-application can't fetch events. Graph API is always returning an empty array `data: []`.

I have full understanding for this. Now I tried to follow these new requirements and had a look on how to submit my App for review. But that's where my struggles began:

## The specific problem

The whole form for applying for review is aimed to Apps for end-users, not server-side bots.

I should provide details on why I'm using `manage_pages` or `publish_pages`. Well okay...

1. When selecting "automated posting" there immediatly a message pops up, telling me, that this is not allowed. Of course it is not - for applications that post in the name of persons without their knowing and aggreement. But my App is posting in the name of my own Facebook Page and I'm the only user and I'm knowing what's going to be posted. So I have to select "Other" and enter a custom description. No problem.
2. But at the end of the form there's asked for a Screencast! What should I make a movie of? Should I make a slideshow of my code? I can't save this form without that Screencast.

I want to be conform to the new Facebook processes, but I simply don't know how to become approved nor at least fill out for review...
I know this is not a programming question but Facebook directed me here.
So I hope I find a Facebook official or Facebook developer here. Thank you so far!

Comment: "my App is posting in the name of my own Facebook Page and I'm the only user and I'm knowing what's going to be posted" - in that case, there is no need to go through review. unless that has changed too...

Comment: There is need, cause I can't access the other Pages' events anymore...

Comment: that´s not possible at all right now, login review will not fix that.

Comment: That "no need for review if only used by admin" loophole of course has to be fixed, too - otherwise people could still use such apps to suck data from public pages on a large scale. Perhaps they will limit this to objects the user actually owns/has admin access to, or something like that.